# Переписать c Python на Java метод, генерирующий hash для Android PIN кода

Tags: java, python, криптография, хеширование

Всем привет. Пытаюсь переписать метод на питоне. Он генерирует хэш по паролю и соли.

```
def hashDefault(passcode,salt):
    salted_passcode = passcode + salt
    guess_digest = hashlib.sha1(salted_passcode).digest()
    md5_digest = hashlib.md5(salted_passcode).digest()
    guess_hash = hexlify(guess_digest).upper()
    md5_hash = hexlify(md5_digest).upper()
    return guess_hash + md5_hash
```

Нужно переписать его на Java и я попытался так:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String pass = "2222";
        String salt = "3107878434153198571";
        String hashToCheck = "D876F4523F3D315B83FF22B2FFA51BB2732778BBD651415DC558CA96FA71E26C6EDB17E2";
        System.out.println(hashDefault(pass, salt).equals(hashToCheck));
    }

    private static String hashDefault(String pass, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] saltedPassword = (pass + salt).getBytes();
        byte[] sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(saltedPassword);
        byte[] md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(saltedPassword);
        return (toHex(sha1) + toHex(md5));
    }

    private static String toHex(byte[] ary) {
        final String hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte anAry : ary) {
            ret.append(hex.charAt((anAry >> 4) & 0xf));
            ret.append(hex.charAt(anAry & 0xf));
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
}
```

Но почему-то Java генерирует хэш неправильно.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что это Java неправильно что-то считает? У меня ваш код (на Java) генерирует строку `95F600B5E866D4D9AEB4A1BC7D5FF57195A61F1038138FC603EDE1FA7C270B76860FB8DE`. Первые попавшиеся сайты по [SHA1](http://www.sha1-online.com/) и [MD5](http://www.md5.cz/) согласны с этим результатом

Comment: И не по вопросу: [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/3432401) предлагается `toHex`, который, скорее всего, будет работать быстрее

Comment: @Regent, я idiot :)) у меня в скрипте соль проходит через `hex` функцию) Сделал тоже самое в java `String salt = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong("3107878434153198571"));
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписал невнимательно. В питон скрипте соль конвертировалась в hex строку (этот код был вне метода, я его не заметил). Сделал тоже самое в java коде.

```
byte[] saltedPassword = (pass + Long.toHexString(salt)).getBytes();
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/278257)

Comment: @hedgehogues, это мой ответ на мой вопрос :D

Comment: @Flippy это как-то по-особенному происходит? Потому что просто замена `(pass + salt)` на `(pass + toHex(salt.getBytes()))` не даёт нужного результата

Comment: @Regent, обновил ответ

Comment: @Flippy то есть `salt`, на самом деле, - это `long`, а не `String`? Внезапно :) Но и в этом случае у меня результат не сходится